# Can GameObject automatically find references?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and going through a simple breakout clone.  Currently, i'm working on a game manager and trying to switch between panels as the ui.

However, unity can't seem to find the PanelMenu object from my project and I keep getting a null instance error.

I'm not sure why this error is suddenly popping up since I didn't (or don't remember) accessing panel objects from GameObject previously.

Here's my code and unity hierarchy:

[image: panel ui code]

[image: unity ui]

Can someone explain to me why GameObject cant find the panels or how to assign the panel instance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your panel objects as prefabs, like you've done with Ball, Player, etc. then change your panel references in your game manager class to `public` instead of `private`.

Then, when you click on your game manager in the inspector, you'll see your panel references listed under its properties (they will be unassigned). Drag the appropriate panel prefabs from your assets browser into the correct properties on your manager object.

Comment: I decided to Serialize the fields.  The tutorial i was watching didnt do this step and I thought GameObject was capable of assigning instances somehow.

Comment: Changed my answer a bit - forgot to mention creating your panels as prefabs. Without your panels being instantiated into the world first, your gameobjects won't find them. So it comes down to spawning them manually in code, or using the prefab + inspector property approach, which is the cleanest option for a UI imo.

Comment: thats cool! Just to clairify, if i decided to use my panels as a prefab gamebobj would be able to find them?

Comment: If you give your panels names or tags, sure, you can find them. `GameObject.Find("name")` and `GameObject.FindWithTag("yourtag")` are your friends - just don't use them during update loops, as they're known to be pretty slow overall. Keeping them inside of initialization/start functions would be the most efficient. But remember - they won't find a gameobject that hasn't been instantiated in the scene yet!